# #IfWinActive not work properly with other shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am trying to use the following code in autohotkey.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; So that we can partial match window title

; Fix MRU in NetBeans
#IfWinActive, NetBeans IDE
{
    ; CTRL+TAB
    ^Tab::SendInput ^{PgDn}
    return

    ; SHIFT+CTRL+TAB
    +^Tab::SendInput ^{PgUp}
    return
}
```

Its work properly when there is no other code in the script file. But my script file also contains other code like `#w::Run, mblctr.exe`. When I use both code in the autohotkey, only the code which comes first works and the second don't work. i.e. in this example only Windows+W shortcut works.

```
#w::Run, mblctr.exe

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; So that we can partial match window title

; Fix MRU in NetBeans
#IfWinActive, NetBeans IDE
{
    ; CTRL+TAB
    ^Tab::SendInput ^{PgDn}
    return

    ; SHIFT+CTRL+TAB
    +^Tab::SendInput ^{PgUp}
    return
}
```

Ho can I fix this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; So that we can partial match window title

; Fix MRU in NetBeans
#IfWinActive, NetBeans IDE
    ; CTRL+TAB
    ^Tab::SendInput ^{PgDn}
    return

    ; SHIFT+CTRL+TAB
    +^Tab::SendInput ^{PgUp}
    return
#IfWinActive

#w::Run, mblctr.exe
```

Comment: Pleae accept this answer, so that others will know you don't need help anymore.

Comment: Saved! Without the instruction`SetTitleMatchMode, 2` didn't get the windows name.